# Javascript OnClick toggle scroll

Tags: javascript, dom

This code disables scrolling once a button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to reactivate the scroll. I think the problem might have something to do with:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
```

I have tested the `if`/`else` statement and that seems to work if I, for example, change the background color of the body.

```
var isScrollEnabled = true;

document.querySelector('.mobile-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle("mobile-menu");

    function noscroll() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    if (isScrollEnabled = true;) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
        var isScrollEnabled = false;
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
        var isScrollEnabled = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix is to use a global variable:

```
var isScrollEnabled = true;
document.querySelector('.mobile-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle("mobile-menu");

  function noscroll() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  if ( isScrollEnabled ) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
    isScrollEnabled = false;
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
    isScrollEnabled = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean that will hold the current state of the scroll.

change the boolean when the button is clicked every time. And use it in the if/else you mentioned